# Proof of boundedness of a real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\epsilon>0$. And let $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be two sequences of reals numbers s.t, for a given natural number $N\geq 0$ , $|a_n-b_n|\leq\epsilon$ $\forall n\geq N $. Prove that if $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded $\implies \langle b_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded. (I'm not bothering with the reciprocal)

I did the proof but I found an issue in it:

Steps:

$|a_n-b_n|=|b_n-a_n|$

$|b_n-a_n| \geq|b_n|-|a_n|$

$|b_n-a_n|+|a_n| \geq|b_n|$

Since  $\langle a_n \rangle_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded then $\exists$ an real number $M\geq 0$ st $|a_n|\leq M$ $ \forall n \geq 1$, then we wave

$\epsilon+M \geq |b_n|$

Now, how can I ensure that the above inequality is true for all naturals $n \geq 1$? (note that $|a_n-b_n|\leq\epsilon$ $ \forall n\geq N$ and not for $\forall n\geq 1$)

Comment: Given $N$, you know that $|b_n|$ is bounded by some $B$ for $n \ge N$. Then you know $|b_n| \le \max(B,|b_1|,...,|b_{N-1}|)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ok.. and $B\geq \epsilon+M$ right?

Comment: All you need is some bound for the 'tail' of the sequence. Then you are left with the $\max$ of a finite number of things which will be finite.

Comment: Yes, i got this. And the bound for the tail is any number $B$ st $B\geq \epsilon+M $

Comment: Well, $B$ just needs to be a bound for $|b_N|,|b_{N+1}|,...$. $M+ \epsilon$ is also a bound. They need have no obvious relationship.

Comment: ok, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that for $n>N$ that $\epsilon + M\ge |b_n|$, you then take the maximal value of $|b_1|, |b_2|, \cdots, |b_N|, \epsilon + M$ as the bound for $|b_j|$. You know that this value exists as you have finite number of elements to take maximum over.

Alternatively you can use a similar reasoning to show that $|a_n-b_n|$ itself is bounded (since every sequence with a limit as $n\to\infty$ is bounded).

Answer (score 1):

Here $a_n$ bounded implies that there exists $M>0$ such that $|a_n|<M$ for all $n$. We know that for some $N$ we have $|a_n-b_n|<\epsilon$, $\forall n \geq N$. Using the triangle inequality and rewriting $|b_n|$ we have that;

$$|b_n|=|b_n-a_n+a_n| \leq |a_n-b_n|+|a_n| <\epsilon + M$$

Now you have the result for $k \geq N$, and you wish to now show $|b_j|<M_1$ for $j<N$. Well this is a finite set. Therefore, if we set $\delta = \textrm{max} \{|b_1|,...,|b_{N-1}|\}$ and $\tau = \textrm{max}\{M+\epsilon, \delta\}$ then given $\epsilon >0$ we have $|b_n|< \tau$.